# Highstock.js diagram is working strange?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

The problem is that if I turn off **TB1S1** off before I turn **TB2S1** and **TB3S1** the dynamic line changes its shape, very strange. But if I let **TB1S1** be on, and turn off  **TB2S1** and **TB3S1**, then the dynamic line stays perfect.

To see the problem, just turn off **TB1S1**, and look at the lines **TB2S1** and **TB3S1** changing its shape.

How can I solve this problem that the diagram holds its shape without being attached to TB1S1..?

```
[JSFiddle - Demo][1]


  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/2jccfson/1/
```

Kind regards, 
Dler H.

Comment: Sorry, just copy this link to see the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/2jccfson/1/

Comment: See [this bug report](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1347) - first series is connected to the navigator, when hidden it doesn't update navigator. Workaround is to use separate base series for the navigator and add points there too.

Comment: Thank you for the link. But I can not figure out how to solve the problem..

Comment: Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/2jccfson/5/ - you can uncomment #25 line to set display most up-to-date data, but that will prevent users from using navigator at all.